# Why 'mention graph' of genuflect is so steep?

Tags: history, historical-change

Google *define genuflect* you will got a 'mentions graph' of *genuflect*. It's very interesting that the graph is very steep while graph of other words, *run* for example, are very smooth. Any idea why this happens?

[image: Google results for "define genuflect" showing spikes in mentions in the 1920s and 1940s, declining in the 1950s]

[image: Google mentions graph for "run," showing more uniform popularity compared to "genuflect"]

Comment: Could the spikes reflect the sudden growth of religious faith/church attendance due to post-war effects?  It would be interesting to comparison graph post-war surges in marriages/birth rates next to 'genuflect'

Comment: ... a sort of knee-jerk reaction?

Comment: @ThirdNews You employ an interesting infinitive there 'to comparison'. Not come across that before!

Comment: 'genuflect' is pretty rare and so it is likely that any single use that is propagated will change frequency highly. The word was popularized by Tom Lehrer in [Vatican Rag](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pvhYqeGp_Do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mitch's point in the comments is most likely the explanation. "genuflect" is used much less often than a word like "run" and [if you plot them together](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=genuflect%2C+run&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgenuflect%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crun%3B%2Cc0), the "genuflect" usage is a flat line at the bottom of the scale.

So the basic answer is that any line with enough data points will be smoothed by Google's graphic software to look like it does in the plot for "run". "Genuflect" will not receive the same treatment because there aren't enough data points.